# How to display image from base64 string in lua for Corona

Tags: lua, base64, coronasdk

I'm using Corona SDK.

I have a TableView using widget.newTableView.

I need to display images that are stored in JSON as base64 on each row.

```
local dirDataTable=json.decode(jsondatastring) --This is JSON data
dirDataTable[rowindex].image ->contains image as base64 string for row number= rowindex
```

How to display an image from this?

Comment: Decode the base64 string first with `mime.unb64()` then, because corona doesn't have functions for drawing a picture from a string, write the file to disk (`io.tmpfile()` might be useful, unless you should cache it), finally use corona's drawing functions to draw it.